# What is the configuration in log4j.xml for rotating the logs based on time as well as size

Tags: java, log4j

Kindly let me know if there is a way to rotate the logfiles based on time as well as size.

The log file is required to be in a format logfilename.log.date when the roll over happens based on time.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do the rotation based on time [DailyRollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html) probably is the best practice. You can have yearly, monthly, hourly etc logs based on your configuration.

If you want size based rotation [RollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html) could be very useful.

Furthermore, if you want to use both time and size at the same time I would suggest you to take a look at [TimeAndSizeRollingAppender](http://www.simonsite.org.uk/), free under the Apache 2.0 license, which claims to be providing full features of both DailyRollingFileAppender and RollingFileAppender.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at DailyRollingFileAppender and RollingFileAppender.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html

Comment: Can anyone kindly let me know how to use the features of RollingFile Appender(rotate based on size) and dailyrollingfileappender(to rotate base on time) in the same configuration. Tried following http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/log4j-user@logging.apache.org/2008-07/msg00355.html, but the rotation based on size is not happening.Tried setting the size to 3KB.